# How to remove empty objects from array PHP Laravel 8.0.x

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, php-8

I have an array, I just want to remove all empty objects from the array.
Here is my array.

```html
{
    "tags": [
        {
            "tags": [
                "php tutorial",
                "php tutorial in hindi"
            ]
        },
        {
            "tags": [
                "php",
                "php tutorial",
                "php tutorial for beginners",
            ]
        },
        {},
        {},
        {
            "tags": [
                "HTML",
                "CSS",
                "JavaScript",
            ]
        },
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

I only want to auto-remove all of empty {} from my tags array. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should first decode the json using `json_decode()` then use `array_filter()` method on. It will filter empty values of the array.

```
array_filter( json_decode($your_array) )
```

Comment: Here i got an error : json_decode(): Argument #1 ($json) must be of type string, array given

Comment: I thought your input is a json. So, if it's an array, just use `array_filter( $your_array )`

Comment: same results even after doing that.

Comment: What is the type of your input? String(json) or php array?

Comment: Input type is a PHP array

Comment: So, you can simply use `array_filter()` method. Read about it [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)